# What kind of software do I need to make general MIDI playback on my computer sound better?

Tags: midi, software, synthesizer

[No, I'm not asking for a specific recommendation.]

I'm writing some web-based software that uses the WebMidi API to output MIDI events which, somehow (sound card MIDI module?) turn into sound. It works. It sounds bad, of course.

I want it to sound better on my computer.

I'm having trouble finding the name of the category of software I would need to get to act like a MIDI device, to produce higher quality sound. I thought it would be called a "software sound module" or a "virtual MIDI synthesiser" but I'm not having any luck.

To be clear, the thing I expect to find would basically sit invisibly in the background.

I'm not looking for:

- a virtual keyboard
- a GUI for creating new instruments
- an extensive sample library
- a plugin for a DAW (since I don't have a DAW)

Just something that synthesise common instruments into something that sounds a bit less terrible than the built-in MIDI synth, using General Midi.

What do I search for?

Comment: What do you use currently, the thing that sounds bad? What is the thing that currently receives your program's MIDI messages and produces sound output? Find out what it's called, and then find a better one? By the way, the combination of an instrument plugin plus a host application together could be called a software sound module.

Comment: (The actual question would of course be, are there any decent and recent alternatives to NI Bandstand, but that would be off-topic here.)

Comment: I think the MIDI device that is being used is called "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth".

Comment: The thing with the Microsoft synth is, it's also a MIDI driver which provides a MIDI port, in addition to being a software sound module. And the MIDI port can be seen by your WebMidi application. To make a software sound module like NI Bandstand visible to WebMidi, I guess you'd need to hook it up to a MIDI port with a virtual MIDI cable of some sort. For replacing the Microsoft GS Wavetable synth with something better, there's an old question on another StackExchange site https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24288/how-do-you-change-the-default-windows-midi-with-something-better

Comment: Thank you - I did not know about that SE site.

Comment: I think the question would make much more sense here, because it's a rather common issue in music-making, when doing certain kinds of MIDI work.

Comment: What you're looking for is a program (or library/module) that provides a virtual MIDI *input* port, and is able to load samples *or* has a system to load "plugins" (a *host*) that either use samples on their own, or generate sound in other ways. Start by looking for "soundfont player" or "soundfont host". Note that most DAWs (including free ones) can also be used as plugin "hosts", and since they normally expose midi ports, you can theoretically access them from the MIDI device list of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called a SoundFont. There are many soundfonts that sound better than the built in Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth.

[FluidSynth's GitHub](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/SoundFont) lists some useful resources.

Comment: I think a SoundFont is just the data file though - you need something to load it into to. Like, as you suggest, FluidSynth?

Comment: How a sound sounds depends on the SoundFont it was created with. The MIDI program can use different SoundFonts to give different types of sounds. Some SoundFonts are for music and others are for games. When your MIDI file is played by somebody else, unless they use the same soundfont as you do, it will sound different.

Comment: Various software may also actually play the same soundfont slightly different.